# Moving average signal confidence

Tags: confidence-interval, autocorrelation, mean

Please advise how best to approach the following;

I have a trend following trading signal comprising a trailing simple moving average over n data points.  The data is stationary.  Currently i calculate a z-score based on the n data points, and judge the signal strength of the newest data point as the value of its z-score.

What alternatives might offer a better indicator of the strength of signal?  It's worth noting that the data exhibits negative first order auto-correlation and  (more difficult perhaps) the degree of negative auto-correlation is not constant - but let's say it varies in a predictable way.

Any pointers about what types of models i should perhaps be considering would be appreciated.

Yug

Answer (score 1):

Using a moving average for a time series with trend may be approprite but is inconsistent with the claim of stationarity. If you have a trend themean is changing with time and the series is non-statistionary.  The moving average model is a special form of an ARIMA model namely IMA(1,1).  If you have a linear trend taking a first difference could make the residual series stationary. My suggestion is to fit the more general ARIMA models and pick the one that fits best which may or may not be exponential smoothing (i.e. a simple first order moving average).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look at ARIMA models as you suggest.  I wondered if you have any thoughts on how to approach the second part?  Consider a time series trade prices for a security.  The observed prices tend to be negatively auto-correlated because of jumping between the bid and ask (eg first trade gets done at the bid price, next trade at the ask, etc).  In this way, the degree of negative auto-correlation depends on market liquidity (which isn't stable).  If i want to incorporate a dependency between the auto-correlation and my measure of market liquidity, how to think about doing that?

Comment: The text by Box, Jenkins and Reinsel provides details about how to determine the form of an ARMA model based on the shape of the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions.  Foe example if the first order autocorrelation is negative and the function then alternates in sign decreasing exponentially it suggests a first order autoregressive process with coefficient ρ < 0.  That is the model is Xi=ρ Xi-1 + ei where ei is a random error term with mean zero.